# HTTP Error 500.19 in IIS- how to fix this?

Tags: asp.net, iis, sharepoint

I am trying to deploy SharePoint web parts I developed in Visual Studio 2010 onto a SharePoint 2010 server. The problem is that when I go to the .svc file in IIS and browse it, I receive the error:

HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error
The requested page cannot be accessed because the related configuration data for the page is invalid.

There's a link on the page that tells me that there's a malformed XML element in my web.config. But I don't see any:

asd

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>

  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
      <identity impersonate="true" userName="******\*******" password=*******>
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
     <behaviors>
       <serviceBehaviors>
          <behavior>
           <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
            <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
               <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
               <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
          </behavior>
       </serviceBehaviors>
     </behaviors>
       <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"/>
     </system.serviceModel>
    <system.webServer>
       <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
    </system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

I am unsure what is causing this. I set up an application pool in IIS for a similar project that has the exact same web.config (with a few minor name changes) and that works. Both are under Default Web Site (and need to). What should I do? where should I look?

Comment: Can you open the web.config file successfully in XML Notepad? It should prompt you if there are errors. Renaming to .xml and attempting to open in firefox should also display any errors encountered.

Comment: Using XML Notepad without changing to .xml leaves all but the first line blank. I can't seem to change the file extension..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just realized it: I have to right-click the Web App project, go to the Web tab, and click on the option to "Use Local IIS Web Server."